# How to create complex value stream with multiple pipelines with Jenkins WorkFlow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

How do you implement a complex value stream with multiple pipelines in Jenkins WorkFlow? Similar like you can do with Go CD: [How do I do CD with Go?: Part 2: Pipelines and Value Streams](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/how-do-i-do-cd-go-part-2-pipelines-and-value-streams).

For a distributed system I would like to have each dev team and operation team to start with their own delivery pipeline. One change needs to trigger only the pipeline of the team that made the change. It needs to trigger a new pipeline that needs to take the latest successful artifacts from each of the team's pipelines and move on from there. This mean that the artifacts from the other teams were not rebuild or retested as they were not changed. And after the Fan In we can run a set of automated tests to verify the correct behaviour of the distributed system with the change.

In the documentation I only find you can pull from multiple VCS's but I assume everything is then build and tested with every change. Which is something I want to avoid.

If each delivery pipeline is in it's own Jenkins Job. How can I visualize the complete pipeline and what is the best way to pull in the last successful artifacts or version from the other pipelines?

Comment: According to the [figure on Go CD's page](http://www.go.cd/) they proceed on the assumption of different source repositories. Which SCM do you use? Which build tool do you use?

Comment: The build tool and SCM are not important for this question as we can control and execute the correct commands with the Jenkins WorkFlow plugin. But for your information, it will be a mix of different tools for building java applications (gradle), docker containers and Linux VM's

Comment: It might be not important for the question but it may be important for the answer.

Comment: We are using GIT for SCM, gradle for java build, docker and puppet for building and provisioning containers and VM's.

Comment: I also edited my question, hoping to clarify it a bit. I added a link to a blog post where they describe a similar setting like I try to solve with Jenkins. I'm trying to implement what they call the project-X-integration on their drawing. But at the moment the only way I can come up with is to have multiple jenkins jobs stitched together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in Jenkins for value streams, and Workflow jobs do not behave any differently in that respect: you can have upstream jobs and downstream jobs correlated with triggers (in this case the `build` step, or the core `ReverseBuildTrigger`), and use (for example) the Copy Artifact plugin to transfer artifacts to downstream builds. Similarly, you could use an external repository manager as the “source of truth” and define job triggers based on snapshots pushed to the repository.

That said, part of the purpose of Workflow is to avoid the need for complex job chains in most situations¹, since it is usually easier to reason about, debug, and customize a single script with standard control flow operators and local variables than to manage a set of interdependent jobs. If the main problem with a single flow is that you need to avoid rebuilding unmodified parts, one solution would be to use something like [JENKINS-30412](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30412) to check the changelog of particular repository checkouts and skip build steps if empty. I think there would be more features needed to make such a system work in the general case that workspaces are clobbered or discarded by other builds.

¹One case where you definitely need separate jobs is that for security reasons the teams contributing to different projects must not be able to see one another’s sources or build logs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each of your dev teams works on a different module of your project and „*One change needs to trigger only the pipeline of the team that made the change*“ I'd use [Git Submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules):

> Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository.

with one repo, that becomes a submodule of a *main* module repo, for each team. This will be transparent to the teams since they just work on their designated repos only.

The *main* module is also the aggregator project for your module projects in terms of the build tool. So, you have the options:

- to build each repo/pipeline individually or
- to build the whole (*main*) project at once.

A build pipeline that comprises one or more build jobs is associated to every team/repo/module.

The *main* pipeline is merely a collection of downstream jobs which represent the starting points of the team/repo/module pipelines.

The build triggers can be any of manually, timed or on source changes.

A decision has also to be made:

- whether you version your modules individually, such that other modules depend on release versions only.

  - Advantage:

    - Others rely on released, usually more stable versions.
    - Modules *can* decide which version of a dependency they want to use.
  - Disadvantages:

    - Releases have to be prepared for each module.
    - It may take longer until the latest changes are available to others.
    - Modules *have to* decide which version of a dependency they want to use. And they have to adapt it every time they need functionality added in a newer version.
- or whether you use one version for the entire project (which is inherited by the modules then): `...-SNAPSHOT` during the development cycle, a release version when releasing the project.

  In this case, if there are modules that are essential for others, e.g. a *core* module, a successful build of it should trigger a build of the dependent modules, as well, so that incompatibilities are recognized as early as possible.

  - Advantages:

    - Latest changes are immediately available to others.
    - A release is prepared for the whole project only once it is to be delivered.
  - Disadvantages:

    - Latest changes immediately available to others may introduce not so stable (snapshot) code.

---

Re „*How can I visualize the complete pipeline*“

I'm not aware of any plugin that can do this with Workflows at the moment.

There's the [Build Graph View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Graph+View+Plugin) which originally has been created for Build Flows, but it's more than two years old now:

> Downstream builds are identified by DownStreamRunDeclarer extension point.
>
> - Default one is using Jenkins dependencyGraph and UpstreamCause and as such can detect common build chain.
> - build-flow plugin is contributing one to render flow execution as a graph
> - some Jenkins plugins may later contribute dedicated solutions.

(You know, „may“ and „*later*“ often become *will not* and *never* in development. ;)

There's the [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) but it apparently is also not suitable for Workflows:

> This plugin provides a Build Pipeline View of upstream and downstream connected jobs [...]

---

Re „*way to pull in the last successful artifacts*“

Apparently it's not that smooth with [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N10621):

> By default, Gradle does not define any repositories.

I'm using Maven and there exist [*local* and *remote* repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) where the latter can also be:

> [...] internal repositories set up on a file or HTTP server within your company, used to share private artifacts between development teams and for releases.

Have you considered using a binary repository manager like [Artifactory](https://sourceforge.net/projects/artifactory/) or [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.com/nexus/product-overview)?

Comment: Hi Gerold, at the moment we are using Nexus for our java artifacts and have a similar build setup like you describe with different jobs glued together with the Build Pipeline Plugin and some custom Groovy scripts. I was hoping Jenkins WorkFlow would provide a cleaner way to define this complex kind of delivery pipeline. I will leave the question open for a week to see if somebody else has a better way to set things up with WorkFlow. And otherwise I will accept your answer as it seems the only way to set it up at the moment and it has useful information.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen, people are moving towards smaller, independent pieces of code delivery rather than monolithic deployments. But clearly, there will still be dependencies between different components. At the very least, for example, if you had one script that provisioned your infrastructure and another that built and deployed your app, you would want to be sure your infrastructure update script was run before your app deployment. On the other hand, your infrastructure does not depend on deploying your app code - it can be updated at its own pace, so long as it ideally passes some testing.

As mentioned in another post, you really have two options to accomplish this dependency:

1. Have a single pipeline (workflow script) that checks out code from both repos and puts them through the same pipeline simultaneously. Any change to one requires the full boat pipeline for everything.
2. Have two pipelines and this would allow each to go at its own pace independent of what the other does. This isn't a problem for the infrastructure code, but it very well could be for the app code. If you pushed your app code to production without the infrastructure update having happened first, the results may not be pleasant.

What I've started to do with Jenkins Workflow is establish a dependency between my flows. Basically, I declare that one flow is dependent on a particular version (in this case, simply BUILD_NUM) and so before I do a production deploy I verify that the last successful build of the other pipeline has completed first. I'm able to do this using the Jenkins API as part of my flow script that waits for that build or greater to succeed, like so

```
import hudson.EnvVars
import hudson.model.*

int indepdentBuildNum = 16

waitUntil{
    verifyDependentPipelineCompletion("FLDR_CM/WorkflowDepedencyTester2", indepdentBuildNum)
}

boolean verifyDependentPipelineCompletion(String jobName, int buildNum){
    def hi = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
    Item dep2 = hi.getItemByFullName(jobName)
    hi = null
    def jobs = dep2.getAllJobs().toArray()
    def onlyJob = jobs[0]   //always 1 job...I think?
    def targetedBuild = onlyJob.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
    EnvVars me = targetedBuild.getCharacteristicEnvVars()
    def es = me.entrySet()
    int targetBuildNum = 0;
    def vars = es.iterator()
    while(vars.hasNext()){
        def envVar = vars.next()
        if(envVar.getKey().equals("BUILD_ID")){
            targetBuildNum = Integer.parseInt(envVar.getValue())
        }
    }
    if (buildNum > targetBuildNum) {
        return false
    }
    return true

}
```

Disclaimer that I am just beginning this process so I do not have much real-world experience with this yet, but will update this thread if I have more relevant information. Any feedback welcome.

Comment: With [JENKINS-31576](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31576) you might be able to use the `buildVariables` property of the upstream build to get this information without direct calls to Jenkins APIs.